# hardware efficient OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have wrote a c++ code, and stored my frame data inside a buffer. Since I am developing my own DSP algorithm to do some eye detection, I need to manipulate the data to suit my algorithm. 
But, the good thing is that I have to apply the same instruction to all the pixels at once. That is why I was wondering if OpenGL has an efficient way of doing this (e.g. multiplying all the pixels by a number at once)?

Unfortunately on the hardware platform that I am working SIMD is not supported for OpenCV, and that is why I cannot use OpenCV. 
However, OpenGL is supported and most function calls are hardware optimized (meaning they can directly talk to GPU).
So, I was curious if performing such functions in OpenGL is possible, and if it is, can any one can give me some sample code as to how I can manipulate large data efficiently.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that in an OpenGL shader. If it's supported, OpenCL will probably be preferable though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.  The basic gist of it is that you load your input data onto the GPU as texture or vertex data, render it with shaders that do your computation, and then read the results back into memory.  GPGPU.org is a good resource for this kind of thing as they've been around since the pre-CUDA/OpenCL days.

http://gpgpu.org/developer/legacy-gpgpu-graphics-apis

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Glad to find out that there is way to do it.

Comment: By the way, I was just curious if OpenGL can except input data as data  already available on a memory, or it has to read data from a file? Also, does OpenGL offer any hardware Jpeg decoding? or OpenGL doesn't really deal with Jpeg decoding?

Comment: @user2112840: OpenGL does not *accept* input data from anywhere *except* memory. OpenGL doesn't know what a file is. OpenGL doesn't know what JPEG is. OpenGL takes pixels, or images compressed with [certain very specific texture-only formats.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats)

Comment: So texture is essentially a buffer itself, correct? So, I will be loading my data (that is stored somewhere in memory) to some other space in memory (texture), and then Shader uses the data, correct? Is there anyway I can reduce some overhead? Cause it looks like I will be storing twice in memory before Shader can access the data!!!

Comment: Yep, pretty much.  There's quite a bit of overhead getting all that data transferred to the card -- I don't think CUDA/OpenCL really has any advantage here -- the idea is that for the right kind of algorithm you more than make up for that with the computing power of the GPU.